# I need To find how to subtract the current date by another date

Tags: python

So I am trying to make a script to tell you how long you have been alive. It al went good but I can’t find out how to subtract a birthday from the current date as shown in the total variable.

```
import time
## dd/mm/yyyy format
times=(time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
day=(time.strftime("%d"))
month=(time.strftime("%m"))
year=(time.strftime("%Y"))
##questions
born_y=input('what year were you born')
born_m=input('what month')
born_d=input('what day')
##convert to decimal
current_time=int(year+'.'+month+'.'+day)
current_age=int(born_y+'.'+born_m+'.'+born_d)
##find age
total=current_time-current_age
print(total)
```

Comment: [what about using this library ? ](https://github.com/crsmithdev/arrow/blob/master/README.rst)

Comment: Could you please edit your title so it is descriptive of your problem and not just stating you have one?

Comment: Hey is this better

Answer (score 1):

Try using `datetime` instead of `time` like this:

```
import datetime

year = input("What year were you born: ")
month = input("What month were you born: ")
day = input("What day were you born on: ") 

born = datetime.datetime(int(year), int(month), int(day))

age = datetime.datetime.now() - born

print(age.days)
>>> 7549
```

You can then split the`timedelta` object `age` up how you want, or just get the days from `age.days`.

Be aware that this won't work if the user inputs anything other than integers.